# How to create a Dynamic Linq Expression Tree VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, sql-server-2017, linq-expressions

I need to reproduce this query as a dynamic Linq expression, it needs to look like this when it hits SQL server trace.  I haven't been able to find any documentation that helps to piece this together.  I have managed to do dynamic Where, Order By and Count queries but nothing like this.

I already know how to do the where clause and the order by, I need specific help with creating an expression to do the following parts:

```
COUNT(*) OVER ()         AS ROW_COUNT

OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 250 ROW ONLY
```

The end result needs to look like below in the query profiler trace.

```
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql
    N'SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER ()         AS ROW_COUNT
   ,[t0].[Trans Date]        AS [Trans_Date]
   ,[t0].[Trans Time]        AS [Trans_Time]
   ,[t0].[Trans Type]        AS [Trans_Type]
   ,[t0].[Transaction]       AS [Transaction]
   ,[t0].[Misc Info]         AS [Misc_Info]
   ,[t0].[Orig License Qty]  AS [Orig_License_Qty]
   ,[t0].[Chg Qty Total]     AS [Chg_Qty_Total]
   ,[t0].[Chg Qty On Hold]   AS [Chg_Qty_On_Hold]
   ,[t0].[New License Qty]   AS [New_License_Qty]
   ,[t0].[Total Qty of Item] AS [Total_Qty_of_Item]
   ,[t0].[User Name]         AS [User_Name]
   ,[t0].[Order Num]         AS [Order_Num]
   ,[t0].[Line No]           AS [Line_No]
   ,[t0].[Receiver ID]       AS [Receiver_ID]
   ,[t0].[Item ID]           AS [Item_ID]
   ,[t0].[Item Description]  AS [Item_Description]
   ,[t0].[Type]
   ,[t0].[RFID]
   ,[t0].[License No]        AS [License_No]
   ,[t0].[Old Loc]           AS [Old_Loc]
   ,[t0].[New Loc]           AS [New_Loc]
   ,[t0].[Pick Container ID] AS [Pick_Container_ID]
   ,[t0].[Category ID]       AS [Category_ID]
   ,[t0].[Reason]
   ,[t0].[Device RF IP]      AS [Device_RF_IP]
   ,[t0].[User ID]           AS [User_ID]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 1]     AS [Custom_Data_1]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 2]     AS [Custom_Data_2]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 3]     AS [Custom_Data_3]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 4]     AS [Custom_Data_4]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 5]     AS [Custom_Data_5]
   ,[t0].[Custom Data 6]     AS [Custom_Data_6]
FROM
    [wms].[vwAuditLogNew] AS [t0]
WHERE
    ([t0].[Orig License Qty] IS NOT NULL)
    AND ([t0].[Trans Date] = @p0)
ORDER BY
    [t0].[Trans Date] DESC
   ,[t0].[Trans Time] DESC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 250 ROW ONLY'
,N'@p0 datetime'
,@p0 = '2020-04-01 00:00:00';
```

Here is my linqpad sample, AdvancedSearchClass just creates the WhereClauseExpression.

```
Dim Queryable As IQueryable(Of vwAuditLogNew) = vwAuditLogNews.AsQueryable
Console.WriteLine(Queryable.ToString())
Dim MasterPE As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(vwAuditLogNew), GetType(vwAuditLogNew).Name)
Console.WriteLine(MasterPE.ToString)
Dim source = Expression.Parameter(GetType(vwAuditLogNew), "p")
Console.WriteLine(source.ToString())
Dim tbl=Queryable.Expression
Console.WriteLine(tbl.ToString)
Dim dp=Expression.PropertyOrField(source,"Trans_Date")
Console.WriteLine(dp.ToString())
Dim CountMethod =Gettype(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(Function(x) x.Name="Count" AndAlso x.GetParameters.Length=1).MakeGenericMethod(GetType(vwAuditLogNew))
console.WriteLine(CountMethod.ToString)
Dim AdvancedSearchClass = New AdvancedSearchClass(Of vwAuditLogNew) With {
            .Queryable = vwAuditLogNews
        }
Dim PredicateBody As Expression = AdvancedSearchClass.WhereIsNotEmpty("Orig_License_Qty")
Dim whereClauseExpression As Expression = AdvancedSearchClass.WhereClauseExpression(PredicateBody)

Dim cnt=Expression.Call(CountMethod,whereClauseExpression)

Console.WriteLine(cnt.ToString)

Dim qry=Queryable.Provider.CreateQuery(cnt)
Console.WriteLine(qry.ToString())
```

Comment: Do you really need `Console.WriteLine` here in the question?

Comment: Do you need same query or same result?

Comment: I need the first part, the structure, is the important part. I'm nesting 2 CTE's, using cross join, offset, fetching, etc.  I really need help with this, the second part is just me trying to figure this out with Linq pad but as you can see I didn't get very far.

Comment: Linq wasn't design to fully replace raw sql. Especially such complicated queries like in your example. Why you want replace it with the Linq? What benefits you are going to gain from it?

Comment: As alternative approach you can separately load from database results of both CTE asynchronously and combine them in the vb.net code.

Comment: The requirements have changed slightly query is a bit easier, can I update the question?

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: `.Skip(0).Take(250)` would do `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 250 ROW ONLY`

Comment: Excellent, now how do I recreate that with Linq Expressions?

Comment: `.Skip(0)` and `Take(number)` are Linq expressions

Comment: Sample of the kind of expression I am talking about.

Dim MasterPE As ParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(GetType(vwAuditLogNew), GetType(vwAuditLogNew).Name)

Comment: From the imports

System.Linq.Expressions